# getting lat long from mapView iphone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, android-mapview

all , iam developing an ipad app that uses mapview to display google maps, my problem was how to get lat long of a perticular region, some how i manged to get by putting an overlay on the map view and getting point of that view , then converted to lat long. now my problem is i want to show an movable pointpin on the view so that user easily point the required region. 
If any idea please send me .

Thanks 
Kumar Y R

Answer (score 0):

Use DDAnnotation in map view
[here](http://digdog.tumblr.com/post/744530746/mapkitdraganddrop-3) is the link to download

it has a sample where you can drag the pin and drop it where you need.